# Javascript forEach Console.log without lambda like syntax

Tags: javascript, lambda

I am going through a JS Book (Modern Javascript for the Impatient) and came across this example, which had a different output than what I was expecting.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numbers.forEach(console.log)

1 0 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
2 1 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
3 2 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

When I use a lambda expression like syntax, I see the right (expected) result.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3]
numbers.forEach(number => console.log(number))

1
2
3
```

How is the expression being evaluated in the first case? Is the lambda expression syntax always expected?

Comment: There are three parameters being passed in to console.log, they are the array element, the index and the whole array.   The second example just logs the array element.

Comment: @James yeah, I only just realised that `(number)` was only included in the second example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (lambda) syntax.

[`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) accepts a series of arguments.

The callback signature for [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is:

```js
forEach((element, index, array) => { /* … */ })
```

So, for every invocation of the callback (`console.log` in your example), the series of arguments is displayed in the console.

Answer (score 1):

foreach sends in more than just the value. It also sends in the index and original array as arguments 2 and 3. These leak into console.log using the non lambda syntax.